# Why do genetic algorithms work? And when do they stop working?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, genetic-algorithm

I have been learning some algorithms for chemical development, and I ran into genetic algorithms. So I wrote a simple GA that tries to zero in on a target string from a given set of symbols (genes).

So,
`genes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890, .-;:_!\"#%&/()=?@${[]}"`
and `target = to be or not be that is the question`.

This is my header file:

```
#a chromosome in a genetic algorithm is a possible solution to the problem

import random 

genes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP \
QRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890, .-;:_!\"#%&/()=?@${[]}"


class Individual: 
    #define some properties 
    def __init__(self, chromosome):
        self.chromosome = chromosome #the actual solution 
        self.fitness = self.calc_fitness() 
        
    def mutated_genes(self): 
        #mutate the genes you have in an Individual 
        gene = random.choice(genes) 
        return gene 
    
    def create_gnome(self, target):
        gnome_len = len(target) 
        return [self.mutated_genes() for _ in range(gnome_len)]
    
    def mate(self, par2):
        #mate with another individual 
        #child chromosome 
        child_chromosome = [] 
        for gp1, gp2 in zip(self.chromosome, par2.chromosome):
            #generate a random number 
            prob = random.random() 
            
            #if prob is less than 0.45, accept gene from parent 1 
            if prob<0.45:
                child_chromosome.append(gp1)
            elif prob < 0.9:
                child_chromosome.append(gp2) #if between 0.45 and 0.9, accept gene from parent 2
            else: 
                child_chromosome.append(self.mutated_genes()) 
                
        return Individual(child_chromosome)
                
    def calc_fitness(self):
        #calculate a fitness score
        #this is the number of characters in the string which 
        #match the target 
        fitness = 0
        for gs,gt in zip(self.chromosome, target):
            if gs!=gt:
                fitness += 1
        return fitness
```

This is my driver code:

```
%run "string_search.ipynb"
population_size = 100 
target = "to be or not to be that is the question" 
generation = 1 #setting up generations to evolve  
found = False #boolean 
population = [] 
#generate a population 
for i in range(population_size):
    indiv = Individual([])
    gnome = indiv.create_gnome(target)
    population.append(Individual(gnome))
while not found: 
    #sort the population in increasing order of fitness score 
    population = sorted(population, key = lambda x:x.fitness)
    #if the individual having lowest fitness score is 0, then we stop the search
    if population[0].fitness == 0:
        found = True 

        break 
    #otherwise, create a new generation 
    new_generation = [] 
    #10% of the fittest population goes to the next generation 
    s = int(0.1*population_size)
    new_generation.extend(population[:s])
    
    #from 50% of fittest population, individuals will mate to produce offspring 
    s = int(0.9*population_size)
    for i in range(s):
        parent1 = random.choice(population[:50]) #choose some individual from the top 50%
        parent2 = random.choice(population[:50]) #choose another individual from the top 50%
        child = parent1.mate(parent2) 
        new_generation.append(child) 
    population = new_generation 
    generation += 1 
    str_chr = "".join(population[0].chromosome)
    print("Generation: {} \t String: {} \t Fitness: {}".format(generation, str_chr, population[0].fitness))
```

This is my result:

```
.
.
.
Generation: 14465    String: to be or not to be that is the 8uestion     Fitness: 1
Generation: 14466    String: to be or not to be that is the 8uestion     Fitness: 1
Generation: 14467    String: to be or not to be that is the 8uestion     Fitness: 1
Generation: 14468    String: to be or not to be that is the 8uestion     Fitness: 1
Generation: 14469    String: to be or not to be that is the 8uestion     Fitness: 1
Generation: 14470    String: to be or not to be that is the question     Fitness: 1
```

I am a little fascinated by how this algorithm managed to come up with the string upto one character away (`question` is `8uestion`).

My question is, why do Genetic Algorithms work as well as they do?
Why do they plateau at `Fitness = 1` for a long time before actually converging to the true solution?  Why does increasing the population size improve convergence rate? If I changed the probability of accepting parent 1 instead of parent 2 by fitness score, would the algorithm get better?

I have been trying to understand this, but most blogs simply implement some code and empirical state that greater the population, better the convergence time. I would appreciate any advice you have for me.

Comment: This is almost certainly better suited for [computerscience.se]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh okay. sorry I did not know of that SE

Comment: They generally work if small changes in the "genotype" correspond to small changes in the "phenotype" (in your case those are the same, so that checks out). Here, they plateau at fitness==1 since it takes some luck to randomly mutate the single last wrong gene (first pick the right gene to mutate, and then mutate it in the right way). In the beginning, more random mutations will lead to an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, this task is very well fit for a genetic algorithm since there are obvious choices for fitness, crossover and mutation. You keep the individuals with the most correct characters and recombine them which makes the chance of ending up with very similar strings really high. Each character contributes to the fitness independently, there is no interaction between 'genes' which means each character can be optimized independently.

As it comes to the last bit of fitness loss that remains for a long time, this is due to random mutations that you have implemented. If both parents are only one character differing from the target, chances are high the offspring will match the target exactly. However, 10% of each new chromosome is generated at random, likely introducing additional loss. While the mutation is critical for exploration, you might want to reduce the mutation rate near the end of the optimization process, at least for a part of the population in order to be more exploitative and less explorative. This will likely get you to your desired fitness of `0`.